# Relation between ground state energy and the potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, schroedinger-equation, ground-state

I am given the following Hamiltonian:
$$H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + \lambda|x|^3$$

where $\lambda$ is a positive constant.

Is there a relation between the ground state energy of $H$ and $\lambda$ i.e. is there any $f(\lambda)$ such that $E_{ground}\propto f(\lambda)$?

Comment: Are you asking if the ground state energy depends on $\lambda$? Or are you asking if the dependency is some simple function of $\lambda$?

Comment: I am asking if the dependency is some simple function of $\lambda$. Actually my notes say: $E_{ground}  \propto \lambda^{2/5}$. But my notes do not explain why.

Comment: I would guess that if you solve the eigenvalue equation for the TISE with the given Hamiltonian symbolically in $\lambda$, you'll notice the power law dependence in the exponent for the smallest eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple dimensional analysis. Work out a [variational estimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variational_method_(quantum_mechanics)) of $\langle E_{gnd}\rangle$ with a normalized Gaussian test function,
$$
\psi ={e^{-x^2/(2a)}\over \sqrt[4]{a\pi} },\leadsto \\
\langle E_{gnd}\rangle = \int\!\! dx ~~ {e^{-x^2/a}\over \sqrt{a\pi} }\Bigl (-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} (x^2/a^2- 1/a)+\lambda |x|^3\Bigr )\\
= \alpha /a + \beta \lambda a^{3/2}, 
$$
where *α,β* are positive constants you need not compute; after you scale the variables, you get simple Gaussian moments, uninteresting, as you are only interested in the functional dependence of *a* on *λ* !!

You now minimize the energy expectation w.r.t. *a*, so the vanishing variation yields
$$
0=-\alpha/a^2 + (3/2)\beta \lambda a^{1/2}, \leadsto 
a\propto \lambda^ {-2/5} , ~~~~ \leadsto  \langle E_{gnd}\rangle\propto \lambda ^{2/5}.
$$